# How to determine in applicationDidBecomeActive if triggered from a notification or springboard?

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I have seen similar questions with answers stating to check the `launchOptions`, but i'm asking how to detect a user that has already launched the app previously. In other words, how do i detect an icon tap vs push inside `func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)`

Comment: Not sure why this question is getting downvoted, i most certainly did search SO, and although many sound similar to many questions, "active" is a very different meaning from launch, which has been answered numerous times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of calls in the app delegate for notifications.  If they don't get called, you were started some other way (not necessarily Springboard -- could be app-switcher, a deep-link URL -- perhaps other ways in the future).

Those should be called before `applicationDidBecomeActive`, but if not, you will have to delay until you find out if they are going to be called.

Comment: Cool, i'll go RTFM on app delegate lifecycle, but would you think an appropriate strategy would be to set a flag during notification delegation methods, and then check that flag on `applicationDidBecomActive` while resetting the flag on app resign?

Comment: I think that might be the only way.